# Collection Set constructor

Tags: java

No entiendo la diferencia entre estas dos formas de declarar un constructor:

```
    Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set set2 = new HashSet();
```

A efectos prácticos que diferencia hay, porque funcionar funcionan los dos o eso parece.

Gracias anticipadas,
Un cordial saludo

Answer (score 1):

En la primera declaracion estas usando generics lo cual va a limitar a tu estructura(HashSet) a solo soportar datos de tipo Integer en la segunda al no hacer uso de **generics** soporta cualquier dato de tipo Object y como practicamente todo en java serian un objeto inclusive los datos primitivos a traves de los **wrapper class(Integer,Double etc)** entonces tendrias una estructura que soportaria cualquier tipo de dato.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set set2 = new HashSet();


    set2.add(1);
    set2.add("string");
    set2.add(new Object());

    set1.add(1);
    set1.add("string"); //error de compilacion
    set1.add(new Object()); //error de compilacion
}
```

Comment: Hola, la sentencia:     set2.add(new Object()); //compila porque Integer hereda de Object
me da error. No se puede castear de un objeto de una superclase a un objeto de una subclase no?

Comment: @pelaitas en efecto tienes razon, ya corregi la respuesta.